# SingleLiveEvent with Buffer with coroutines

Tags: android, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to build a replacement of [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) in which there is a buffer to avoid loosing events when a new one comes before the old one is consumed.
The goal is to have an Android ActivityViewModel that emits events, and several fragments that consume those events. This means that when one fragment is destroyed it stops its subscription, and when a new fragment that is interested in those events is started, it should subscribe to it. In other words, it should be possible to have 0, 1, or more subscribers.

I am trying to build this with kotlin coroutine channels with the following code. In the ActivityViewModel that emits events:

```
val userEvent = Channel<UserEvent>(Channel.UNLIMITED)
suspend fun onUserEvent(event: UserEvent) {
    userEvent.send(event)
}
```

In the fragment that should subscribe:

```
override fun onCreateView(...) {
    (...)
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        sharedViewModel.userEvent.consumeEach {
            // do something with event
        }
    }

}
```

The problem that I am facing is that a fragment consumes these events, but whenever its scope is cancelled the channel is also cancelled. Then another fragment subscribes and when the ActivityViewModel tries to `send` it crashes with `JobCancellationException` because `userEvent.isClosedForSend` is true.

If I use GlobalScope.launch instead it is not cancelled. But then I lose the lifecycle handling (starting subscription after start, cancelling after destroy).

So, how can I keep the channel open and still handle the lifecycle? And is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Channel`, use `BroadcastChannel`.

ViewModel:

```
protected val eventSender = BroadcastChannel<UserEvent>(Channel.BUFFERED)
val eventReceiver = eventSender.asFlow()

suspend fun onUserEvent(event: UserEvent) {
    eventSender.send(event)
}
```

Activity/Fragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(...) {
    (...)
    viewModel.eventReceiver.onEach {
        // do something with event
    }.launchIn(lifecycleScope)
}
```

Using this combination of `BroadcastChannel` + `Flow`, a new `ReceiveChannel` is created when your screen opens the subscription and only this `ReceiveChannel` is closed when the View is destroyed.

[Detailed information can be found here](https://medium.com/@cesarmorigaki/replace-singleliveevent-with-kotlin-channel-flow-b983f095a47a?source=friends_link&sk=3301f1b1afafddd7f03d33c4e94e46c4)

Answer (score 0):

I was using also mentioned answer then i realised that it remembers previous event when user navigate quick through the app. Solution for me came with this:

```
    private val _effect = Channel<CurrenciesEffect>(1)
    val effect = _effect.receiveAsFlow().conflate()
```

and in Fragement

```
    private fun observeEffect() = lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        currenciesViewModel.effect.collect { viewEffect ->
            ...
        }
    }
```